# Prepared statements for zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, prepared-statement

I am using zf1. The Modal query is:

```
$select = $postTable->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from('posts')
        ->joinLeft('users', 'users.id = posts.user_id', array('post_first_name' => 'first_name'))
        ->where('posts.property_id = ?', $id);

$postTable->fetchAll($select);
```

I am trying to use prepared statement for this query. I haven't figured out how to convert this into prepared statement so please help me by converting this query into prepared statement.

Comment: what do you mean be `prepared statement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use like below

```
 $params = array($property_id);

   $sql = "SELECT post_first_name as first_name " .
                 "FROM posts" . 
            "left join users on users.id = posts.user_id WHERE posts.property_id =  ?";
           $stmt = $db->query($sql, $params);
            $dealers = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

above is just procedure code you can set your column name and table name as you require.

Hope this will sure help you.